# How to Find the Probability of a Distribution based on another Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, computer-science

The question is :
Suppose we first sample $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and then sample $Y \sim N(X, 1)$.
What is the probability that $P(Y \leq 2)$?

I know how to sample the $X$ distribution, but I'm not sure how to get the $Y$ distribution based on $X$.

Comment: You know that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y|X=x\sim N(x,1)$. From these facts you can derive the joint pdf $f_{(Y,X)}$ and then marginalize (i.e., integrate) to obtain the pdf $f_Y$. You will find that $Y\sim N(0,2)$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I jointed the pdf but I didn't get Y ~ N(0, 2). Could you explain more about how you derive the Y distribution?

Comment: Another way of looking at this is to have $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Z=(Y-X)\sim N(0,1)$ where $Z$ is independent of $X$.  Then $Y=X+Z$ is normally distributed with mean $0+0=0$ and variance $1+1=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y|(X=x)\sim N(x,1)$ as Gabriel Romon pointed out.

We are in the continuous case so we have that $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)$.

$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}$

$\implies f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{2x^2+y^2-2xy}{2}}$

and $f_Y(y)=\int f_{XY}(x,y)dx$.

Finally, $P(Y\leq 2)=\int_{-\infty}^2f_Y(y)dy$. You'll have to do the last integrals yourself.